# Can't import packages

Tags: go

I'm trying to import a subdirectory I have in my project to my main file, but for some reason I get this error:

```
could not import ./service (no package for import ./service)
```

This is how I import:

```
import (
"os"

"service"
```

)

I also tried `"service/app"`

```
"./service/app"
```

`"./service"` nothing works, always the same error.

I'm trying to use the app.go file
This is the file structure:

```
Project Directory
        -- main.go
        -- service (directory)
           -- app.go (file)
```

I tried to restart VS Code, tried to use go install/update tools, nothing works.
Also, this is my main func:

```
func main() {
  a := &service.App()
  a.Initialize(
    os.Getenv("APP_DB_USERNAME"),
    os.Getenv("APP_DB_PASSWORD"),
    os.Getenv("APP_DB_NAME"),
  )

  a.Run(":8010")
}
```

`&service.App()` does not show a problem, but when I remove the "`service`" import, it does say

```
undeclared name: service
```

So I don't understand what the problem is.
This error sometime show on the "os" import too, I don't know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Golang [doesn't support relative imports](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#do-modules-work-with-relative-imports-like-import-subdir).

> In modules, there finally is a name for the subdirectory. If the parent directory says "module m" then the subdirectory is imported as "m/subdir", no longer "./subdir".

So, in your case you should import `service` package as `your_module_name/service`.